# "Sanginjoll" - Prononciation d'un nom propre

Tags: prononciation

Bonjour,

Je voudrais savoir comment les Français prononcent ce nom propre: "Sanginjoll".

Est-ce que cela se prononce comme /sɑ̃.ɡɛ̃.ʒɔl/ ou comme /sɑ̃.ʒɛ̃.ʒɔl/?

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ce patronyme n'existe pas en français. Il n'est donc pas possible de trouver de prononciation familiale de référence.

Il s'agit en fait d'un nom créé dans le récit en question pour des lecteurs germanophones qui ne maîtrisent pas les subtilités des règles de prononciation française.

Il est donc beaucoup plus logique que le *G* soit prononcé comme s'il était suivi d'un *U*, ceci d'autant plus que ce nom est très vraisemblablement un jeu de mot commençant par *sang*, puisque le personnage en question est un boucher dont les vêtements et le commerce sont assez **sanguinol**ents...

La prononciation anticipée est donc, à l'allemande :

- /zan.ɡi.ɲɔl/

ou à la française :

- /sɑ̃.ɡi.ɲɔl/, ce qui correspond à un jeu de mot avec *guignol* (**sang-guignol**)

Voici une confirmation de la prononciation :
(https://www.welt.de/print/die_welt/literatur/article110059499/Die-Rattenfaenger-von-Paris.html) :

> *Monsieur Sanginjoll, der schlechteste Mensch, den Luca kennt, ist im Besitz der magischen Formel und damit der absoluten Macht über alle Ratten der Stadt. Er ist Pferdemetzger, unterwegs mit schwarzem Geländewagen und blutbefleckter weißer Schürze – sein Name reimt sich auf Grand Guignol, das legendäre Theater des Grauens und der Verbrechen.*

Traduction:

> Monsieur Sanginjoll, la pire personne que Luca connaisse, est en possession de la formule magique et donc d'un pouvoir absolu sur tous les rats de la ville. Il tient une boucherie chevaline, voyage dans une grande voiture noire et porte un tablier blanc taché de sang - son nom rime avec [Grand-Guignol](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand-Guignol), théâtre légendaire de l'horreur et du crime.

Comment: Merci, je pense que c'est tout à fait logique!

Answer (score 1):

En première lecture, j'aurais tendance à lire /sɑ̃.ɡɛ̃.ʒɔl/ à cause de l'alternance du g et du j.
Mais cette prononciation aurait besoin d'un "u" supplémentaire Sanguinjoll.
Donc la façon la plus "académique" est définitivement /sɑ̃.ʒɛ̃.ʒɔl/

Comment: Rester près de l'orthographe est ce qu'il y a de plus sensé.

Answer (score 0):

Je suis de l'avis de [user Loïc Di Benedetto](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/14698/lo%c3%afc-di-benedetto). Cependant, il serait utile de savoir que certaines personnes ne le partagent pas ([réf.](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sanginjoll-prononciation.3734095/#post-19059529)) au cas où le nom serait un nom étranger ; dans le cas d'un nom français il y a cependant confirmation.

Par exemple pour un nom étranger "[san.dʒin.dʒɔl]" pourrait être  la prononciation idéale selon ces personnes. Je trouve cela cependant contraire à la systématique du français qui veut que l'on prononce par exemple « Jonathan » avec un « th » à la française et non à l'anglaise.